# How to get the top most youtube channels by subscribers count

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have gone through the youtube api but couldn't find an api which will give me the channels list based on subscribers count. There are ways to sort based on date, relevance, views, videos etc, but not based on subscribers count.
If someone knows a way to get the channels list by subscribers count, please help me.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, there's no such Youtube Data API endpoint (one that will provide *the list of channels that have the highest number of subscribers*). The [Search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint comes close with parameters `type=channel` and `order=viewCount` w.r.t. responding to the following query: obtain *the list of channels that have the highest number of viewers*.

Comment: You may try to appeal to Google (for example, on it's [issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/)), for them to add a new parameter like `order=subscriberCount` to the `Search.list` endpoint. I deem that to not be an intricate feature to implement. (Disclaimer: I myself am not a Google employee; my statement is no more than an educated guess!)

Comment: If you choose to open a feature request on Google's issue tracker, please do not forget to link that page back here, such that other interested users to follow it.

Comment: Created a new request in google issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158553843 Let's see how it goes.